# laravel-jsvalidation dosent work if the open tag and inputs's tags are not in the same div

Tags: laravel, validation

im using proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation to validate a form but im having an issue when the open tag and inputs's tag are not in the same div the validation does not run

my view page

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$_SESSION["name"]='Depense';
$_SESSION["icon"]='icon-shuffle';
$_SESSION["active"]='depense';
?>
@extends('layouts.default_layout')
@section('content')
@include('partials.menu')
@include('partials.messages')
<div>
    {{ Form::open(['action' => 'DepensesController@depenseOperations','methode' => 'POST','id'=>'form_depenses']) }}    
    {{Form::date('date_operation', '',['class'=>'form-control' ,'placeholder'=>'Date de depense'])}}
</div>
<div>
    {{Form::number('montant', '',['class'=>'form-control' ,'placeholder'=>'Montant versé'])}}
    {{ Form::button('<i class="la la-plus icon-submit-table"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-float btn-square btn-outline-primary','name'=>'action','value'=>'add','data-toggle'=>'tooltip','data-placement'=>'top','data-original-title'=>'Ajouter','data-popup'=>'tooltip-custom','data-bg-color'=>'primary','data-text-color'=>'white'] ) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
<!-- Laravel Javascript Validation -->
@push('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('vendor/jsvalidation/js/jsvalidation.js')}}"></script>
{!! $validator->selector('#form_depenses') !!}
    @endpush
@endsection
```

my controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $validator = JsValidator::make($this->validationRules);
        return view('pages.depenses')->with('validator',$validator); 
    }

    protected $validationRules = [
        'date_operation' => ['required','date'],
        'montant' => ['required'], 

    ];
```

Comment: Does it work when they're kept in same div?

Comment: yes the "date_operation" input will work but "montant" will not